# Python Search and Replace regex for large file

Tags: python, regex, nltk

In python to search and replace some special characters in 1GB file im using a regex list

```
def myreplace(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text 

rep={"&":"and","-":"",'?':''}

achive=map(lambda x: myreplace(x, rep), achive)
```

Currently the performance is fine in the 1 GB test file. Would like to know if it is possible to make this perform better. Is there a better way to do this within NLTK?

Comment: Is each character mapped to a unique replacement? Otherwise, you could make a class `([put all your chars in here])` look up the replacement.

Comment: Yes each character is  mapped for a unique replacement like &-and. the list can go up to 100

Comment: Is `myreplace()` the same as `replace_all()`?

Comment: Yeap they both are same , ive corrected it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably faster to use a translation for the two single characters you need to remove and only one replacement for the ampersand. In this way you parse the string only two times instead of three.

```
achive = achive.translate(None, '-?').replace('&', 'and')
```

Comment: Yes this looks feasible. Is there hack on this to expand replace  list to say 100 more ?